# Javascript - How to Read Multiple PDF files from single zip file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, unzip

I have to upload a zip file by input and zip file contains multiple pdfs and text files and i have to read only pdf files from zip file.
is it possible with https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js ?